# Python turtle window not visible in Linux Fedora

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, fedora, python-turtle

I am working with Python in linux Fedora.

Running the following short program, for a short moment, I see a small window in the left-top side of the screen, but the program stays on running.

I think I have to add something more in the program.

I have test it with at the end `mainloop()` or `time.sleep(15)`, but with the same result.

turtleshape.py

```py
import turtle

turtle.shape('turtle')
n = 0
f = 0
while n < 200:
    turtle.forward(f)
    turtle.right(15)
    f += .1
    n += 1
```

Comment: Your code was all on one line. I edited to move it onto multiple lines. Can you validate that it's as intended? Thanks. `turtle.mainloop()` at the end should work. Can you share that attempt? Are you sure there are no error messages in the `sleep` and `mainloop` attempts?

Comment: Sorry, it is the first time I ask something in this splendid forum. Thank you very much to correct and answer my question. I have added turtle.mainloop() at the end, but the result is the same. With sleep or mainloop, I see no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
dnf install python3-tkinter
```

or

```
dnf install python3-tkinter.x86_64
```

Comment: Packet python3-tkinter-3.11.5-1.fc38.x86_64 is already installed. Thank you very much for the promt reply.